# How can I click a button multiple times and repeat the function?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, random, transform

I am new to app development and am starting by writing a 'Wheel of fortune' app in Xcode. I have a button and a wheel, and when I first launch the app I can click the button and the wheel will spin, however if I click the button again nothing happens and I have to restart the app, to click the button and make it spin. I have enclosed the code that I've used. I would appreciate if anyone take a look over my code and help me :)

[The image of my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zf9bP.png)

Here's my code in case you can't open the image.

```
import UIKit

import AudioToolbox

import AVFoundation

var count = 1

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var Wheel: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
    
    @IBAction func rotateButton(_ sender: Any) {

        playSound (sound: "spinSound", type: "mp3")
        
        var usedNumbers = [Int]()

        let rotateButton = Int.random(in: 1...20)
        Label.text = String(rotateButton)

        if usedNumbers.contains (rotateButton) {

        } else {

        usedNumbers.append(rotateButton)

        }
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: Double(rotateButton)) { () -> Void in
          self.Wheel.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(rotateButton))
        }

            UIView.animate(withDuration: Double(rotateButton), delay: Double(rotateButton)/2, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations:  { () -> Void in
            self.Wheel.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(rotateButton))
        }, completion: nil)
            }
}
```

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but note that `usedNumbers` is initialized each time you enter your function and will never contain anything when you test it.

Comment: @PhillipMills how would I be able to fix this problem as I was about to ask how to stop it changing every time. A fix to my program and an explanation on to where I went wrong would be greatly appreciated. :)